# An application that resembles Lion's save windows when logging out

Tags: software-recommendation

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 in a virtual box, and I'm wondering if there is an application (or package) that resembles Lion's automatically-open-everything-up-when-you-logged-out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly what you're asking for, but since it's a virtual machine, you could save the state of the machine instead of shutting down so that it will be in exactly the same state when you start it next.